# Merging two vectors, but keeping unique elements of only one vector

Tags: r

Maybe easy question, but i failed nevertheless.

I have two vectors:

```
v1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "F", "G")
v2 <- c( "B", "C", "F", "G", "H","I")
```

I want to merge `v1` and `v2` to obtain a vector which contains all common elements and all unique elements of `v2`, but does not include any unique elements of `v1`.

Essentially, remove all "FALSE" of

```
> v1 %in% v2
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

but keep all "FALSE" of

```
> v2 %in% v1
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

plus any common element.

Desired output:

```
c("B", "C", "F", "G", "H","I")
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: So you basically want `v2` ...?

Comment: Maybe this: `c(intersect(v1,v2), setdiff(v2,v1))` ?

Comment: Don't you need to have "A" in the desired output?

Comment: "A" is an unique element of v1, so should be removed from the desired output.

Comment: @RLave this works nicely in this example, but not in my real life example. i need to figure out why. thank you very much so far.

Comment: @nouse If your 'v2' is `B, C, F, G, Z, H, I, B` and 'v1' is the same, what would be the output

Comment: @nouse Do you need `stack(setNames(list(v2, v1), 1:2)) %>% add_count(values) %>% filter(ind == 1| n > 1 & ind == 2) %>% filter(!duplicated(values)) %>% pull(values)`

Comment: Create a function `f1 <- function(vec1, vec2) {

 i1 <- vec1 %in% vec2;
 i2 <- ! vec2 %in% vec1;
 c(vec1[i1], vec2[i2])

};
f1(v1, v2)`

Comment: its basically about this: i have list with ~500 model objects. the names of this objects are v1. i now have a different set of models (which names or v2), which partially overlaps with the initial list. to the existing list i want to add anything that is new in v2, and removes anything from the existing list which is not in v2, but leave anything else untouched. I think i am going to revise this question and post a new, more specific one.

Comment: @nouse can you test the function i posted earlier

Comment: @akrun, thank you very much. the function is giving the desired output. i however missed the context and caused confusion. maybe you can have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027906/removing-and-appending-elemets-from-and-to-a-list-based-on-a-vector-overlap