# removing and appending elemets from and to a list based on a vector overlap

Tags: r, list, append, subset

I have a list with ~ 500 model objects. The names of this objects are v1:

```
existing.list <- vector("list", 3)
v1 <- names(existing.list) <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

I now get different dataset, which i need to model, too, and save in the same list. The objects in this new dataset are overlapping with the some of the objects in `existing.list`. Because it is very time-consuming, i do want to keep the old results. The names of this new dataset are v2:

```
v2 <- c("B", "C", "D")
```

I first want to remove the objects in v1, which are not in v2, then append to existing.list all the new, unique names from v2.
I can do the first task in a rather complicated way:

```
rm <- v1[!v1 %in% v2]
rm.i <- which(v1 %in% rm)
v1 <- v1[-rm.i]
```

But then i fail at appending the new objects, as determined by the unique elements in v2:

```
new.elements <- v2[!v2 %in% v1]
```

The desired output is a modified `existing.list`, with intact elements "B" and "C" and a new empty element "D". Basically, its a list with elements determined by the names in `v2`, but for a number of reasons it would be complicated to just create a new list and copy parts of `existing.list` to it.
Since i need to do this for a number of lists, a less complicated way than i am doing now would be handy.

Thank you very much in advance! This is a last minute addition to a project, so any help is highly appreciated!

this question is based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026040/merging-two-vectors-but-keeping-unique-elements-of-only-one-vector), which i sloppily worded and thus created confusion. My thanks to those users, who still tried to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can first get the names of elements that are in `v2` but not in `v1`

```
tmp <- setdiff(v2, v1) # "D"
```

And then subset `existing.list` and append it as follows

```
existing.list <- c(existing.list[v1 %in% v2], 
                   setNames(vector("list", length(tmp)), tmp))
```

Result

```
existing.list
#$B
#NULL

#$C
#NULL

#$D
#NULL
```

Comment: exactly, what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Are these what you are looking for?

```
intersect(v1, v2)
# [1] "B" "C"

setdiff(v2, v1)
# [1] "D"
```